# Email Failed from Android app using Server

Tags: php, android, email, smtp

I'm using :

- Linode server CWP 7 installed on it.
- Website + Android App

Currently Working :

- Website user can register and get verification email easily

What's Not Working:

- When they uses Android app for registration they won't get email But user get registered
- I tried PHPmailer + Amazon SES both have issue with APP but not with website.

API error

```
{"message":"Could not send verification email","code":400,"errors":{"error_id":"17","error_text":"Could not send
verification email"},"data":[]}
```

My server already installed

-Postfix Mail Server
-Dovecot IMAP/POP3 Server

Script Developer reply me

> Your server gets involved if your server doesn't have SMTP support then SMTP will not work.

My services
[image: Services Installed]

Except this other APIs are working fine after registration user can login.
Is there something I'm missing or need to installed any kind of services to user SMTP or Mailer from outside of this website ?